# How to choose a random record out of the greatest N records efficiently(not using sub query) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, random, sql-optimization

```
select .. from (
    Select ... from ... order by weight desc limit N
    ) order by rand() limit 1
```

The above needs to create a temporary table each time,which is not efficient,so it doesn't qualify.

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the `Rth` row from an ordered result set where `R` is a random number.  If so, then it seems the LIMIT option with two parameters is the one you want. The first parameter could be the random number from `1 to N`:

```
SELECT ... order by weight desc limit R,1
```

I don't have MySQL installed, so I can't test it.  So I do not know if R can use RAND() directly or if it would have to be precomputed.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Though LIMIT clause can not contain expressions in MySQL. `COUNT(*) >= N` should also be true.

Comment: @SQL: If you generate random value in client code and the count of rows in a table is less than N, the random value can fall outside the range and the resulting query would return no rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at:

http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

There are several suggestions for implementing this while avoiding table scans, including:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id >= (
        SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` 
    ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It's different,my problem is to select a random row out of **the greatest N**